# Sed awk text formatting

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to filter and order text files with something like awk or sed. It does not need to be a single command, a small bash script should be fine too.

```
#
home: address01
name: name01
info: info01
number: number01
company: company01
#
name: name02
company: company02
info: info02
home: home02
#
company: company03
home: address03
name: name03
info: info03
info: info032
number: number03
company: company032
#
name: name04
info: info04
company: company04
number: number04
number: number042
info: info042
```

I only need name, number, and info. There is always exactly one name, but there can be 0,1 or 2 number and info. The # is the only thing which is consistent and always on the same spot.

output should be:

```
name01,number01,,info01,
name02,,,info02,
name03,number03,,info03,info032
name04,number04,number042,info04,info042
```

What I tried so far:

```
awk -v OFS=',' '{split($0,a,": ")} /^name:/{name=a[2]} /^number:/{number=a[2]} /^info:/{info=a[2]; print name,number,info}' > dump.csv
```

Comment: Show some efforts to solve the problem.....

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the logic to print on '#' or after the last line (assuming last block not terminated with #):

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
{split($0,a,": ")}
/^name:/{name=a[2]}
/^number:/{number=a[2]}
/^info:/{info=a[2]}
/^#/ { print name,number,info}
END { print name,number,info}
' < w.txt  > dump.csv
```